# Android MVVM UI control

Tags: android, mvvm, visibility

I'm started to learn MVVM with LiveData on Android. I think displaying and updating basic data is clear to me. The topic I struggle to find a best practice for is controling the UI.

Let's say I have a basic UI, a form for example. It has a few EditTextViews to input data. At the end it also has a switch. If it is **ON** a few more EditTextViews are shown to fill in. When it's **OFF** of course they are gone.

My question is where to implement this logic?

1. In the Activity/Fragment code? Then business logic would be involved in the VIEW part of MVVM (which I don't find great).
2. In the ViewModel? Then business logic would exist in a, let's say,  *data cache*. This way I would have to create a bunch of `boolean` getters in the ViewModel which compute the values for separate View visibilities. Then in my Activity in the subscription block for LiveData change I need to read all of these values and set visibility for the views one-by-one.
3. In a separate Service/Helper/Util class? It would be the same solution as #2 just the logic extracted from the ViewModel.

What is the best practice here? Same question can come up with the topic of user input validation though (and I guess there are a number of these areas).

Comment: Is the On/Off state affecting something other than the UI visibility? If there was no UI, what is its role in the business logic?

Comment: When it's ON, business logic fills fields respectively in a POJO, when it's OFF the same fields are left empty/cleared out. For example if the **Under Age** switch is ON the user must enter the data of the legal representative (name of the mother etc.), and these data need to be saved.

Comment: the way I understand it, it's driven from UI (user clicking the button) not derived from other POJO properties, e.g. date of birth vs now? If user switches the button on, fills in the fields and turns it off, the POJO should have empty values regardles of fields being not empty in the UI, correct?

Comment: Correct. Yeah I know now that this example is not the best. Being underage must be calculated from birthdate and current date in most use cases as you mentioned. It was just a quick example of a scenario when sometimes a few UI components need to be shown and sometimes need to be gone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd go with the 2nd approach, but slightly different implenetation (using DataBinding), inspired by Google's sample Sunflower app:
https://github.com/android/sunflower
It's supposed to be introducing Jetpack best practices, including MVVM.

> Then in my Activity in the subscription block for LiveData change I need to read all of these values and set visibility for the views one-by-one.

Instead of doing that you can subscribe your layout to the viewmodel (with DataBinding), similar to this:
https://github.com/android/sunflower/blob/master/app/src/main/res/layout/fragment_plant_detail.xml

```
    <data>
        <import type="com.google.samples.apps.sunflower.data.Plant"/>
        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="com.google.samples.apps.sunflower.viewmodels.PlantDetailViewModel" />
    </data>
```

and then use set the visibility based on the references to the viewmodel without getters, in the layout itself

```
app:isGone="@{!viewModel.isUnderAge}"
```

or

```
android:visibility="@{viewModel.isUnderAge?  View.VISIBLE : View.INVISIBLE}"
```

Comment: To be honest I would avoid DataBinding if it is possible. I have 2 reasons:

- Like I said in my #1 option in the original question, that would put business logic into the VIEW layer of the app.
- I'm generally not keen on with solutions when you write code into a `string` and let the background architecture execute it as code. And if everything seems ok (no typos, compilation problems and so on) the right functionality would happen. I would avoid it as far as possible, it's really against my taste of source code.

Comment: Read this article about why it is dangerous: https://medium.com/@hellotimmutton/an-argument-against-data-binding-13e2aaf7a9b1

Comment: I've read it before and while I agree with the importance of separation of concerns, I disagree with his interpreation. The model should work with any UI attached to it, so e.g. `android:visibility=”@{viewModel.showTitle ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}”` is a bad example - it describes the UI state, not business logic state. If in the business logic there is a state in which you prefer to not show the title then add observable reflecting that state, and let UI react to it (e.g. by hiding the title, and maybe some other views - this is what I would do in the Fragment or with the databinding)

Comment: I will use the #2 method as we discussed, but try to do with LiveData.